# Ansible - how to use selectattr with yaml of different keys

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

im pulling my hairs trying to do a simple thing (i thought it should be easy) with parsing a yaml and filtering for some key in Ansible.

My yaml file looks like this:

```
---

- vm: "vm1"
  ip: 10.10.10.1
- vm: "vm2"
  ip: 10.10.10.2
- test_vm: something
- another_vm: something_other
```

so i thought than an expression like

```
lookup('file','my_file.yaml') | from_yaml | selectattr('vm','search','vm1')|list
```

would work but it gives an error like

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ lookup('file','{{sysfile}}') | from_yaml | selectattr('vm','search','vm1')|list}}): expected string or bytes-like object"}
```

If i remove the test_vm and another_vm keys it works fine.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ip": "10.10.10.1",
            "vm": "vm1"
        }
    ]
}
```

If i try to search for the test_vm key it fails with:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'test_vm'\n\nThe error appears to be ...
```

Is selectattr filter expecting all the dicts in the list to have the same keys?Because it does not make any sense not to be able to filter a list of custom dicts with Jinja2.

For example if i had a more complicated yaml (not that flat) am i limited to search and filter within Ansible?

For example if i have a yaml looks like this:

```
---

- vm: "vm1"
  ip: 10.10.10.1
- vm: "vm2"
  ip: 10.10.10.2
- test_vm: something
   - process_1: X
   - process_2: Y
   - process_3: Z
- another_vm: something_other
```

how can i quickly filter for the process_2 for example?
Is there a way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is `selectattr` filter expecting all the dicts in the list to have the same keys?

More precisely, it is expecting all dicts in the list to have the attribute you are selecting on. If not all dict in the list have it, you will have to first filter out the items where it is not defined. This can be done with `selectattr` as well. (thanks @Randy for making this clearer since my initial answer).

In your situation, the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) (which implements [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/)) can also do the job in sometimes a more compact manner. But it is not a core filter and requires to have the [`community.general` collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/) installed.

Here are a few examples taken from your above requirements solved with both core filters and `json_query` solutions.

The playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: "Filter data with core filters or json query"
  hosts: "localhost"
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your initial data on a single line for legibility
    test_var: [{"vm":"vm1","ip":"10.10.10.1"},{"vm":"vm2","ip":"10.10.10.2"},{"test_vm":"something","process_1":"X","process_2":"Y","process_3":"Z"},{"another_vm":"something_other"}]

  tasks:
    - name: Get objects having vm==vm1
      vars:
        msg: |-
          With core filters: {{ test_var | selectattr('vm', 'defined') | selectattr('vm', '==', 'vm1') | list }}
          With json_query: {{ test_var | json_query("[?vm=='vm1']") | list }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"

    - name: Get all objects having vm attribute
      vars:
        msg: |-
          With core filters: {{ test_var | selectattr('vm', 'defined') | list }}
          With json_query: {{ test_var | json_query("[?vm]") | list }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"

    - name: Get all objects having process_2 attribute
      vars:
        msg: |-
          With core filters: {{ test_var | selectattr('process_2', 'defined') | list }}
          With json_query: {{ test_var | json_query("[?process_2]") | list }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"

    - name: Get only a list of process_2 attributes
      vars:
        msg: |-
          With core filters: {{ test_var | selectattr('process_2', 'defined') | map(attribute='process_2') | list }}
          With json_query: {{ test_var | json_query("[].process_2") | list }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [Filter data with core filters or json query] *********************************************************************

TASK [Get objects having vm==vm1] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "With core filters: [{'vm': 'vm1', 'ip': '10.10.10.1'}]",
        "With json_query: [{'vm': 'vm1', 'ip': '10.10.10.1'}]"
    ]
}

TASK [Get all objects having vm attribute] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "With core filters: [{'vm': 'vm1', 'ip': '10.10.10.1'}, {'vm': 'vm2', 'ip': '10.10.10.2'}]",
        "With json_query: [{'vm': 'vm1', 'ip': '10.10.10.1'}, {'vm': 'vm2', 'ip': '10.10.10.2'}]"
    ]
}

TASK [Get all objects having process_2 attribute] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "With core filters: [{'test_vm': 'something', 'process_1': 'X', 'process_2': 'Y', 'process_3': 'Z'}]",
        "With json_query: [{'test_vm': 'something', 'process_1': 'X', 'process_2': 'Y', 'process_3': 'Z'}]"
    ]
}

TASK [Get only a list of process_2 attributes] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "With core filters: ['Y']",
        "With json_query: ['Y']"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thx @Zeitounator. I had already looked at json_query and solved my problem.
But I'm glad you responded.Nice example.
The bad thing is that the filters in the jmespath are not quite explanatory.
I was troubling for example filtering with logical or the dictionaries.Anyway in the end i found it, using the contains but still...Jinja2 and jmespath could be better.

Comment: @jkalivas. I came across this now old answer. With time and experience (and taking into account answer from Randy), I thought it was time to revamp my post. Updated with the existing json_query solution in place but with core filters as well.

Answer (score 6):

> More precisely, it is expecting all dicts in the list to have the attribute you are selecting on.

It is not 100% true for all filter functions, to select objects by an attribute not defined by all elements:

```
{{ test_var | selectattr('vm','defined') |selectattr('vm','equalto','vm1') | list }}
```

Comment: You are right. This was written an long while ago when I was basically beginning on SO (and ansible). I adapted my answer. Thanks.