# Ansible incorrect behaviour with when

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

I have task which checks all kibana spaces, and if some kibana spaces doesn't exist it creates it
Here is my ansible code

```
- name: get all kibana spaces
  uri:
    url: '{{ kibana_url }}/api/spaces/space'
    method: GET
    force_basic_auth: yes
    url_username: elastic
    url_password: "{{elastic_ca_pass }}"
  register: spaces_result
```

and here is a output of spaces.result variable ( all kibana spaces that exist )

```
        "color": "#aabbcc",
        "description": "tajikistan kibana space",
        "disabledFeatures": [
            "timelion",
            "canvas",
            "maps",
            "Metrics",
            "logs",
            "apm",
            "Security",
            "uptime",
           "advancedSettings",
            "machineLearning",
            "ingestManager"

        ],

        "id": "tajikistan",
        "initials": "MK",
        "name": "tajikistan"
    },
   {
        "color": "#aabbcc",
        "description": "uzbekistan kibana space",
        "disabledFeatures": [
            "timelion",
            "canvas",
            "maps",
            "Metrics",
            "logs",
            "apm",
            "Security",
            "uptime",
            "advancedSettings",
            "machineLearning",
            "ingestManager"

        ],

        "id": "uzbekistan",
        "initials": "MK",
        "name": "uzbekistan"

    }
],
```

so we have a 2 Kibana spaces ( tajikistan and uzbekistan )

then the next task about to create uzbekistan space

```
- name: create uzbekistan kibana space
  uri:
    url: '{{ kibana_url }}/api/spaces/space'
    method: POST
    body:
      {"id":"uzbekistan","name":"uzbekistan","description":"uzbekistan kibana space","color":"#aabbcc","initials":"MK","disabledFeatures":["timelion","canvas","maps","Metrics","logs","apm", "Security","uptime","advancedSettings", "machineLearning", "ingestManager"]}
    body_format: json
    force_basic_auth: yes
    headers:
      kbn-xsrf: 'true'
      Content-Type: 'application/json'
    url_username: elastic
    url_password: " {{ elastic_ca_pass }}"
  when:
    - '"uzbekistan" not in spaces_result.json'
```

so this task will execute only if uzbekistan not in spaces_result variable but it execute why?

```
ASK [../roles/elasticsearch_nopci_efk_users : create uzbekistan kibana space] ***********************************************************

fatal: [loges-prod-01-uv01]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"statusCode\":409,\"error\":\"Conflict\",\"message\":\"A space with the identifier uzbekistan already exists.\"}", "content_length": "99", "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 08 Apr 2021 09:13:51 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "json": {"error": "Conflict", "message": "A space with the identifier ibank already exists.", "statusCode": 409},
```

so why is it exeucte?

Comment: Because `uzbekistan` is not in `spaces_result.json`. You'll have to go lower in the `name` or `id` property of the dictionnary. This could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858362/ansible-how-to-use-selectattr-with-yaml-of-different-keys

Comment: Hard to be 100% sure without a valid and complete json data structure (your extract can't be used as is...) but basically for the rough idea => `when: '"uzbekistan" not in (spaces_result.json | map(attribute="name") | list)'`

Comment: @Zeitounator excuse me, so a map(attribuste="name" use like grep name=uzbekistan or tajikistan, right?

Comment: The expression in parenthesis creates a list of all `name` attribute values in your `space_result.json` dict list (inferred from your partial extract, edit you question with a full output to be sure....). Then the test checks that "uzbekistan" is not a member of that name list.